# Spring Boot DEBUG logging level stopped working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot DEBUG logging was working just fine with the setting

```
logging.level.com.companyname=DEBUG
```

However now it no longer works such that LOG.debug is not longer outputting despite no changes to the logging properties in the properties file.

If I set the root logging level to debug it does change the output to debug however this is not what I require.

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

I thought that some recent additions to the POM may have caused this to occur however I've deleted those and it had no effect.

**Current POM**
I've had to set a number of exclusions for logging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
    <artifactId>KeepaFBTDownloader</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>APPNAME</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Keepa</id>
            <name>Keepa Repository</name>
            <url>https://keepa.com/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev120-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev48-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myjeeva.digitalocean</groupId>
            <artifactId>digitalocean-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.keepa.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdeferred</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdeferred-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you running this application? Have you tried setting the log level to debug when running (either through run configuration or provided an additional CLI argument)

Comment: @eamon-scullion I'm running the application either by java -jar command or in Netbeans via F6. Both are not logging the DEBUG level. I haven't tried " setting the log level to debug when running (either through run configuration or provided an additional CLI argument.... I'll look into that